# How to get an array of all rows in column A in an Excel file using PHPExel?

Tags: php, class, phpexcel

I have a list on an Excel file of phone numbers (A row). 
How do I get it as an array using PHPExel?

Can I get a whole example including a small explanation of which file from the 'Class' directory I should 'include_once'? How do I know which .php file to include? How do I scan the list?

Comment: Look at the examples in the `/Examples` folder and see what file they're including; and then look at the worksheet's `rangeToArray()` function, which can be used to read a specified range of cells such as `A1:A100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      <?php
/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION START HERE   ****************************/

define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "root"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","database Name here"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

$databasetable = ""; // your table name

/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION END HERE  ****************************/

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel-develop\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';

    $targetfolder = "";
    $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) ;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']). " is uploaded";
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "Problem uploading file";
        print $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) ;
    }

    $inputFileName = basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);

    try 
    {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet

    for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
    {
        $value1 = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
        $Value2 = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
        $value3 = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM "; // your select query
        $sql = mysql_query($query);
        $recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $exist = $recResult["$value1"];

        if($exist=="") 
        {
            $insertTable= mysql_query("//your insert query");

        $msg = 'Record has been added.</div>';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $msg = 'Record already exist. </div>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I have no database 
i want to use an api to get information on each list item and then output it in a new excel file. 
I'll be going through this code tomorrow and get out of it the things I need, 
I'll update you if i get into trouble. 
thanks a lot!